# Password manager bug with Firefox 3.6.13

Tags: firefox, password-management

I'm having trouble with the latest Firefox (3.6.13) password manager. For a website I'm working on, it doesn't fill the password field for any login credential saved. I've looked into the options "Saved passwords" list and they are all there with the correct passwords. I thought at first that the website was blocking this feature in some way, but the password managers in Chrome (on the same Windows 7 machine) and Iceweasel (in a virtual Debian 6 machine) work well. Any idea about what could cause this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally added a submit button to that form and Firefox password manager now work. It was using only a link that submitted the form via JavaScript before.

Answer (score 0):

It occurs with me for some websites... Try using Saved Password Editor addon and edit passwords stored for your page (in the list of saved passwds). Then, see if the field names match or if stored info is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you should use a proper form with normal username (text) and password fields and an action that submits normally rather than submitting it with a script. Otherwise it can't be recognized as a login form. If you use Saved Password Editor, you can see what information Firefox stores for forms; it's more than just the host, username, and password.